# How to gracefully handle uncaught exceptions by showing a generic error UI

Tags: java, android, crash, crashlytics, crash-reports

I wonder how Crashlytics is able to monitor uncaught exceptions through the entire app **on any thread**? does it use global exception handlers or what?

I want to implement similar behavior to gracefully handle uncaught exceptions by showing a generic error UI to the user in addition to logging to a remote server. Is this even possible?

Here's what I tried:

I implemented an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`:

```
public class ActivityExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final Context mContext;

    public ActivityExceptionHandler(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        // logging code
        ...
        ...

        // show error UI
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GenericErrorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("error", e.toString());
        mContext.startActivity(intent);

        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

and registered it in my `BaseActivity`'s `onCreate()`:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ActivityExceptionHandler(this));
```

But this handles **only exceptions on the main thread**, what about other threads?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=How+Crashlytics+works+behind+the+scenes%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=9LeOWvucMMvmugTrtpugAQ

Comment: @NileshRathod did that already :)

Comment: You can go thru this: https://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-avoid-force-close-error-in-android/

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa no code isn't necessarily a bad thing!

Comment: @y.allam, In this case, it seemed to be. Or maybe no research would have been better?

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa updated the question